CIty-data cannot be subscripted -Error compiling cobol program
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. Assignment00.

   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 Temperature PIC 9(3)V9(1).
   01 Counter PIC 9(2) VALUE 1.
   01 City-Names.
      05 City-Name OCCURS 5 TIMES PIC X(10) VALUE 
         'Montreal', 'Ottawa', 'Toronto', 'Kingston', 'Cornwall'.
   01 City-Temps.
      05 City-Temps-Array OCCURS 5 TIMES
         INDEXED BY City-Index.
         10 Temp OCCURS 5 TIMES PIC 9(3)V9(1).
   01 Total-Temperature PIC 9(5)V9(1).
   01 Average-Temperature PIC 9(3)V9(1).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-LOGIC.
       PERFORM VARYING City-Index FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL City-Index > 5
         DISPLAY "ENTER the last 5 daily high temperatures for: " 
         City-Names(City-Index)
         PERFORM ACCEPT-TEMPERATURES
         PERFORM CALCULATE-AVERAGE
         DISPLAY "Average temperature for " 
         City-Names(City-Index) " is " Average-Temperature "C"
       END-PERFORM
       STOP RUN.

   ACCEPT-TEMPERATURES.
       PERFORM VARYING Counter FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL Counter > 5
         DISPLAY "Enter temperature #" Counter ": "
         ACCEPT Temperature
         MOVE Temperature TO Temp(Counter) OF City-Temps(City-Index)
       END-PERFORM.

   CALCULATE-AVERAGE.
       COMPUTE Total-Temperature = 0
       PERFORM VARYING Counter FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL Counter > 5
          ADD Temp(Counter) OF City-Temps(City-Index) TO 
          Total-Temperature
       END-PERFORM
       COMPUTE Average-Temperature = Total-Temperature / 5.

I am receiving these error messages when I try to compile in VS studio code.
Assignment00.cbl: in paragraph 'MAIN-LOGIC':
Assignment00.cbl:32: error: 'City-Data' cannot be subscripted
Assignment00.cbl:32: error: syntax error, unexpected :
Assignment00.cbl:31: error: PERFORM statement not terminated by END-PERFORM
Assignment00.cbl: in paragraph 'CITY-DATA-PROCESS':
Assignment00.cbl:42: error: 'City-Data' cannot be subscripted
Assignment00.cbl:42: error: syntax error, unexpected :
Assignment00.cbl:43: error: 'City-Data' cannot be subscripted
Assignment00.cbl:43: error: syntax error, unexpected :

I am trying to create a simple COBOL program using GnuCOBOL. The program has to accept 5 temperatures for each city and then display the average temperature for each city.
I cannot figure out how to resolve this error.

Please only post the code that corresponds to the error messages. It appears, that before posting the code, you edited the program by replacing City-Data with City-Names.

Cindy - Is the answer useful to you? If yes, then please upvote (also for answers in other posts that you find useful). Does the answer works for you? If yes, then please accept, which marks this question as solved. And in any case: Have a look at the tour, to learn more about how this site works (there are some misconceptions, so it is good to have a quick look, which also gives you the first badge, showing to others, that you do care).

You defined a group with a "table" of 5 names:
   01 City-Names.
      05 City-Name OCCURS 5 TIMES PIC X(10) VALUE 
         'Montreal', 'Ottawa', 'Toronto', 'Kingston', 'Cornwall'.

but then subscript the group:
         DISPLAY "ENTER the last 5 daily high temperatures for: " 
         City-Names(City-Index)

Change that to the variable that actually has several OCCURenceS:
City-Name (City-Index)
